# How to get user email after OAUTH with Google API Python Client

Tags: python, api, oauth

I'm currently building a web app interacting with Google API in Python. Using the oauth to get access to the users resources. After successful authentication and upgrade of the token like this:

```
gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService()
gd_client.SetAuthSubToken(token)
gd_client.UpgradeToSessionToken()
```

Then I can access the different feeds of the API and get a list of the users Youtube videos for example. But the user has only logged in with Google and all I have is a oauth token and no other info on the user. How do I retrieve info on the user? Like email, display name and so on? I have been testing a lot of different stuff without managing to solve this...

I found some interesting here: [Is there a way to get your email address after authenticating with Gmail using Oauth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970794/is-there-a-way-to-get-your-email-address-after-authenticating-with-gmail-using-o?rq=1)

My theory was that I could use the PhotoService.GetAuthSubToken() and then reuse that token to request the contact and get auther.email from the contact entry. Changed the scope of the auth to:

```
scope = ['https://picasaweb.google.com/data/', 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/']
```

witch returns a roken valid for both services... Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I found a great way to do it!

Request the extra scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email then I can access that with a Gdata.Client to get the e-mail address.

Complete example code: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-oauth-demo/

Complete write up of how I got there: http://www.hackviking.com/2013/10/python-get-user-info-after-oauth/

Comment: Kristofer,I've been looking for this for days!  thanks so much for posting the blog!!

Comment: marty331: Happy to share it, it took me a while and a lot of reading, testing and pepsi before I cracked it!

Answer (score 16):

I just want to add a resource I found to be particularly easier to use. Here it is: [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/credentials). 
Kallsbo directed me to a correct location by searching for scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`. After you already have `credentials`, simply use the following function taken directly from that link:

```
    def get_user_info(credentials):
  """Send a request to the UserInfo API to retrieve the user's information.

  Args:
    credentials: oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials instance to authorize the
                 request.
  Returns:
    User information as a dict.
  """
  user_info_service = build(
      serviceName='oauth2', version='v2',
      http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))
  user_info = None
  try:
    user_info = user_info_service.userinfo().get().execute()
  except errors.HttpError, e:
    logging.error('An error occurred: %s', e)
  if user_info and user_info.get('id'):
    return user_info
  else:
    raise NoUserIdException()
```

Call it `user_email = get_user_info(credentials)['email']`, and you already have your email there! :)

Comment: YES! Thanks alot! This is the way to do it with the official google-api library.

Comment: You left out the imports - where does this NoUserIdException() come from? I can't seem to find the appropriate package or module from Google's shitty documentation.