# Google Api get users Email Address

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api

I am using the Google Api PHP client to Log the user in. I want to get the Users Email address. I have the following code.

Scope:

```
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');
```

Code:

```
$request = new apiHttpRequest("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?alt=json");
$userinfo = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($request);

$response = $userinfo->getResponseBody();
print "<pre>" . print_r(json_decode($response, true), true) . "</pre>";
```

This give me only the following details

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [id] => 110084312800396764
>     [name] => Harsha M V
>     [given_name] => Harsha M
>     [family_name] => V
>     [picture] => https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Xusc8lwgLIQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/sOthy23uJGk/photo.jpg
>     [locale] => en
> )
> ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Require Google to return email address as part of OAuth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128981/require-google-to-return-email-address-as-part-of-oauth)

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Comment: Try using `OAuth::fetch` grabbing /auth/userinfo.email (this would return what you are after) and/or /auth/userinfo.profile, and using /oauth2/v1/userinfo (all through www.googleapis.com)

Comment: @Dagon I tried that and it worked. But now i dont have access to Name and Photo. Damn its tougher than i thought. When i try to send multiple scope i still dont get it

Comment: @Alex2k ^^ when i try this i am not able to still get the job done -- $client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the scope in an array does the job.

```
$this->client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));
```

Comment: Not only that, I'm noticing that if you include more than one scope in the array it won't work unless there's only one item in the array. If you have two or more, even if one of them is the one you want, you'll get a "error": "access_denied",
 "error_description": "Requested client not authorized."

Answer (score 1):

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest?next=http://www.example.com/index.php&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&secure=0&session=1 
or
https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest?next=http://www.example.com/index.php&scope=email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&secure=0&session=1
```

both of above links works for me in php