# How to collect e-mail addresses from a click of a button?

Tags: web, google-api, google-plus, contact-form, email-address

My team and I are currently exploring different methods of collecting email addresses from our website visitors.

We want to do something cooler than a contact forms, and we really like the way [quicksprout.com](http://quicksprout.com) handles this and would like to do the same.

Where would I start to implement collecting email addresses through a couple clicks of a mouse via connecting our visitors through google plus api from our homepage? Is this possible to implement through a regular http static html site?

Answer (score 1):

**NO** A server is needed in order to collect email addresses. At least in order to add them to a database. This can *not* be done using just a static html site.

Now, since a server will be needed, you can just access the emails like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012142/google-api-get-users-email-address) (This also avoids a hassle with [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy))

---

**For example:** Let the user login via google oauth, save the user related email in your database. fine
(if the user has saved its login data in its browser or is already logged into its google account in the used browser, this would be a mouse click only solution.)

---

Comment: Thanks for helping me figure out this crucial first step of the puzzle. Would it be too difficult to attach a server just to that component of the site?

Comment: Ok that edit helps a ton. I'm assuming google provides a handler that takes the user through the experience and collects the data and sends the user to the next page and us a token to our database? Could you point me to where I should start to understand converting my static site to support a php database google api could use?

Comment: Can you point me into a direction where I could learn to implement  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012142/google-api-get-users-email-address? I don't know where to put that code. I'm sure I could figure out patterns within it though, but just don't know where to put it. And also what I have to do to my index.html for that code to work. Even if you just help me figure out what to search on google, I'll very much appreciate it! Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: "Php beginner tutorial", "php backend development", "apache server", "database mysql"

Comment: Thanks!! Just curious, would you be interested in assisting us with this? How much would you charge for this task of making this happen on our site? Or even working me through it?

Comment: not necessarily. a server can be omited. for example your page js could add the email to a public google spreadsheet and so on. not secure thou. other free cloud backends can be used like google app engine or apps script.

Comment: Even though there might be free solutions, still there has to be some kind of a "server backend" included.

Comment: @ZigMandel, that's a very interesting thought! I really like this lightweight approach to take the burden off of us and put it on google's servers (if I understand correctly). Could we make the spreadsheet private and allow access from our business? Also, are there existing options for the js that I could add to my page to do this? And lastly, is this where ajax comes in to play?

Comment: these are too broad to answer with comments. if you make it private its more code but also possible by using oauth2 (and solves the security issue i mentioned)